# TYPO3: Add LINK tags to CSS Files in the HEAD tag from within a Typo 3 extension

Tags: php, css, typo3-7.6.x

I have a custom extension in Typo3.

Does anyone know how to add in a template ?

Ive had some success with adding in

```
call_user_func(
    function($extKey)
    {
       //other init code goes here

       $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$extKey] = array();
       $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$extKey]['name'] = $extKey;
       $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$extKey]['stylesheetDirectories'] = array(
        'structure' => 'EXT:'. $extKey. '/Resources/Public/css/',
        );
    }, 
    $_EXTKEY
);
```

Ive looked at [typo3 docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SkinningReference/UseCases/UseCase1LoadAdditionalStylesheetsToSkinTheBackend/Index.html) but cant get it to work when adding to ext_tables.php

It is a Front End Plug in and I want the reference to be contained within the Extension for ease of installation and management.

Anyone  had success with this ?

Answer (score 0):

put following in this file **`your_extension/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts`**

```
page = PAGE
page {
    # CSS files to be included
    includeCSS {
        yourCss = EXT:your_extension/Resources/Public/Css/yourCss.css
    }
}
```

and then call it in your **`ext_tables.php`**

```
/***************
 * Include TypoScript
 */
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
    $_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Your Package'
);
```

you'll find this voice in your template in the backend so that you can include it ...